# Mac Terminal (+bash +tmux +set-o vi) missing characters at end of line

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, vi, tmux

Often when editing a historical bash command in vi mode (after pressing `↑`), and then moving backwards in the text using `b`. When I begin editing the text after pressing `i` or `a`, the extra text I insert pushes the following characters to the right. However, the line length appears fixed, and as characters move right, the line is truncated to the original length of the historical item I am trying to edit.

However, despite these characters being invisible, they are still "there" in the sense that they are executed along with the rest of the command.

Has anyone else ever seen this behaviour or know of a fix?

Note: I am on `Mac OS X 10.10.4` using `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)` inside `tmux 2.0`. Bash is in vi mode using `set -o vi`.

Comment: Does it work in bash outside of tmux?

Comment: Have you customized your prompt to contain terminal commands? The most common issue with the command-line display getting out of sync with the actual text is if you have a prompt that contains non-printing characters not properly surrounded with brackets `\[ … \]`.

Comment: @ChrisPage I'm using the standard Mac OS X prompt... `\h:\W \u\$`

Comment: @ughoavgfhw I think this is only affecting tmux sessions, I'll try & verify that...